# Tracking down an R bug with pair-frequency counting

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

A few days ago this code was working well, but now it has broken:

```r
links <- data.frame(source= c(1:3,4,6,8,10,10,12), target= c(1:3,5,1,10,4,4,9))
#View(links)

#source   target
#  1        1
#  2        2
#  3        3
#  4        5
#  6        1
#  8        10
#  10       4
#  10       4
#  12       9

relations <- links %>%
  dplyr::group_by(source, target) %>%
  count()

#View(relations) #Just getting one column with 2 everytime??
# V1
# 2

#Should've been and it used to be-
#source   target   count
#  1        1       1
#  2        2       1
#  3        3       1
#  4        5       1
#  6        1       1
#  8        10      1
#  10       4       2
#  12       9       1

Have tried %>% summarize(count =n()) too, no luck.
```

This expression was working until now, just this morning re-ran the code, tried tracing back, I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Can yoou try on a fresh R session with only `dplyr` loaded or specify `dplyr::count`

Comment: Hi, akrun, same thing again. Re-ran whole code in a new script. It's doing on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't replicate it.  Can you try on R console instedad of Rstudio

Comment: what is the result of `ls(all.names = TRUE)` in a clean session? where does `count` come from? try `dplyr::count` like you did for group

Comment: @akrun Oh my, it works in the console. I don't get it.

Comment: @rawr I am getting 48 variables, but it is a new file, in a new directory and no count in the list of variable. Also, you kidding me, `dplyr::count` works. It is counting properly now too.

Comment: @rawr Would you mind sharing what could've been possibly causing  this please? Earlier I had `count()` without `dplyr::`, always worked.

Comment: likely one of those 48 variables was a function called "count" which was used instead of the dplyr count. also if you say you are getting 48 objects in a new r session, you likely have the save and restore .RData into workspace options in rstudio--I can't think of any good reason to have these as default options or saving your history for that matter. You can do all of these explicitly with scripts or saving the workspace image, but letting the program take care of it will lead to forgotten objects cluttering up your workspace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posting a solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space).*

Solution to this was given by rawr and akrun, it was basically me missing the scope resolution for `count()` function, should've been `dplyr::count()`.